# How to integrate a license to its Android application?

Tags: java, android, android-lvl

I have a problem with my application: When it opens, it crashes due to the integration of license. But I do not know where the problem is. Please can you help me find it? I will be very grateful!

My main acitivity:

```
package com.example.testouille;

import com.google.android.vending.licensing.AESObfuscator;
import com.google.android.vending.licensing.LicenseChecker;
import com.google.android.vending.licensing.LicenseCheckerCallback;
import com.google.android.vending.licensing.ServerManagedPolicy;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     static final String BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY = "LICENSE";
     private static final byte[] SALT = new byte[] {
            -46, 65, 30, -128, -103, -57, 74, -64, 51, 88, -95, -45, 77, -117, -36, -113, -11, 32, -64,
            89
        };
     private Handler mHandler;
     private LicenseChecker mChecker;
     private LicenseCheckerCallback mLicenseCheckerCallback;
     boolean licensed;
     boolean checkingLicense;
     boolean didCheck;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }



private void doCheck() {

    didCheck = false;
    checkingLicense = true;
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

    mChecker.checkAccess(mLicenseCheckerCallback);
}


private class MyLicenseCheckerCallback implements LicenseCheckerCallback {

    @Override
    public void allow(int reason) {

        if (isFinishing()) {

            return;
        }               
        Log.i("License","Accepted!");       



        licensed = true;
        checkingLicense = false;
        didCheck = true;

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void dontAllow(int reason) {

         if (isFinishing()) {

                return;
            }
            Log.i("License","Denied!");
            Log.i("License","Reason for denial: "+reason);                                                                              



            licensed = false;
            checkingLicense = false;
            didCheck = true;               

            showDialog(0);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void applicationError(int reason) {

        Log.i("License", "Error: " + reason);
        if (isFinishing()) {

            return;
        }
        licensed = true;
        checkingLicense = false;
        didCheck = false;

        showDialog(0);
    }


}

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

    return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("UNLICENSED APPLICATION DIALOG TITLE")
            .setMessage("This application is not licensed, please buy it from the play store.")
            .setPositiveButton("Buy", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(
                            "http://market.android.com/details?id=" + getPackageName()));
                    startActivity(marketIntent);
                    finish();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            })
            .setNeutralButton("Re-Check", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    doCheck();
                }
            })

            .setCancelable(false)
            .setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener(){
                public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                    Log.i("License", "Key Listener");
                    finish();
                    return true;
                }
            })
            .create();
}{
    String deviceId = Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    Log.i("Device Id", deviceId);  
    mHandler = new Handler();
    mLicenseCheckerCallback = new MyLicenseCheckerCallback();
    mChecker = new LicenseChecker(this, new ServerManagedPolicy(this, new   AESObfuscator(SALT, getPackageName(), deviceId)), BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY);
}}
```

My logcat:

```
02-21 15:00:06.530: D/AndroidRuntime(1231): Shutting down VM
02-21 15:00:06.530: W/dalvikvm(1231): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3ab8ba8)
02-21 15:00:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1231): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-21 15:00:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1231): Process: com.example.testouille, PID: 1231
02-21 15:00:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1231): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testouille/com.example.testouille.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-21 15:00:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
02-21 15:00:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
02-21 15:00:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-21 15:00:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
02-21 15:00:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-21 15:00:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-21 15:00:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-21 15:00:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-21 15:00:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-21 15:00:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-21 15:00:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-21 15:00:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-21 15:00:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1231): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-21 15:00:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getContentResolver(ContextWrapper.java:99)
02-21 15:00:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):     at com.example.testouille.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:152)
02-21 15:00:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
02-21 15:00:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
02-21 15:00:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
02-21 15:00:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
02-21 15:00:06.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):     ... 11 more
02-21 15:00:14.370: I/Process(1231): Sending signal. PID: 1231 SIG: 9
02-21 15:01:30.460: D/AndroidRuntime(1251): Shutting down VM
02-21 15:01:30.470: W/dalvikvm(1251): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3ab8ba8)
02-21 15:01:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1251): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-21 15:01:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1251): Process: com.example.testouille, PID: 1251
02-21 15:01:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1251): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testouille/com.example.testouille.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-21 15:01:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
02-21 15:01:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
02-21 15:01:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-21 15:01:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
02-21 15:01:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-21 15:01:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-21 15:01:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-21 15:01:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-21 15:01:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-21 15:01:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-21 15:01:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-21 15:01:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-21 15:01:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1251): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-21 15:01:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getContentResolver(ContextWrapper.java:99)
02-21 15:01:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):     at com.example.testouille.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:152)
02-21 15:01:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
02-21 15:01:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
02-21 15:01:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
02-21 15:01:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
02-21 15:01:30.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1251):     ... 11 more
02-21 15:01:33.890: I/Process(1251): Sending signal. PID: 1251 SIG: 9
```

I am a "noob" in Java on Android ^^ .
Thanks you so much ,
David

Comment: Please post the stack trace from logcat.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been awhile, however if you or someone else is having a problem with the code this way I am fairly sure the error is down where you are getting ready to make you dialog to let the use it fail to get a good license response.

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

    return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
```

Because it is in a class of its own and note in the class

```
class MainActivity extends Activity
```

You can't use "this" because the AlertDialog.Builder requires a Context, you would need something like:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

    new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext())
```

Another option would be to make a public context variable in the MainActivity the you could simply use that.

```
class MainActivity extends Activity{

   public Context context;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
       this.context = this;
   }
```

Then down where you create the Dialog you can use the public context from the MainActivity like this:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

    new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is if you didnt give your application the permissions it needs to run, but I'm apparently not much better than you haha.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately I already permissions ^ ^.